# How to filter simultaneously two tables within a form in Access2007?

Tags: forms, ms-access, filtering

I hope to find some help at last...
I'm using Access2007. My scenario is: I need to keep track of data products' sold to a holding in Brasil. In the end I arrive to have two tables:

1. A cost table for US product shipped
2. A sales table for Brasilian product sold

The PK is the ID_Product_Brasil.

I have created a form where the two tables are displayed, but I don't know how to filter them simultaneously for the ID_Product_Brasil.

Can someone please highlight me??

Comment: Much more info is needed. How does your form show both tables? Do you have two subforms?

Comment: No, they are not subforms, I just created a new empty form then drag and drop the tables I wanted to visualize.

Comment: oh and the table have a connection of "Many-to-Many", if it can help..

Answer (score 0):

Getting the table right is the key to having a database that works. Based on the information you have provided, I do not see the need for two tables let alone two tables with many-to-many relationship(which by the way does not exit, many-to-many relationship consists of 3 tables. 2 main and a link table which has a 1-many relationship with the 2 mains).

I suggest a single table for cost price and sale price and the product should have the same id no matter which country. Try the following:

tblProduct(fldProductID,fldPurchasePrice,fldSalePrice)

Alternatively if you want to keep your current structure you need a form with 2 subforms. Link the form to the product table and the 2 subform to the two tables and use the productID to link the form the the subforms

Comment: @Sheils...given your tip I was trying to sort out properly my tables. I have 3 tables:
1. tblSoldProductsinUS (it has the US Article and the brasialian Article) 2.tblSoldProductinBRASIL (it contains ONLY the brasilian article) and 3.tblArticles, in this latter there is a unique link between the US Article and the brasialian Article. Each table has PK as autonumber. Then when I try to set the relationship among them it keeps giving me an error that I'm using a unique index. What I'm doing wrong??

Comment: list the three tables and their fields and I will see if I can provide further help

Comment: first table fields are: ID,Ordine,Pos,IDPartner,DataOrdine,IDProd_US,IDProd_BRASIL,IDOrdine,DescrIdOrdine,QtaOrd,QtaCons,LME,Premio,Prezzo,PKL,ImportoEUR,DataCons,DataNazionalizz,cambio,Reals,CodFattura,NrBoL,TassaPagareReal,TaxNac,totReal_KG,totRealCompresoRYLT,AnnoCons,MeseCons

Second table fields: ID,FATTURA_BR,Data,Mese,CLIENTE,ANNO,IDProd_BRASIL,ARTICOLO,TIPOLOGIA,QTY,Note,PzvenditaReal,Importo FT

Third table: ID, IDProd_US, IDProd_BRASIL

Thank you Sheils!

Comment: how are they linked together. What the difference between IDProd_BRASIL ,IDProd_BR & IDProd_US. What is the key purpose of each table

Comment: then that code is link 1-to-1 in the third table to an IDProd_US

Comment: 99% of the time its better to replace 1-to-1 tables by a single table. Field from two tables that have the same value and used to link the tables should have the same name, helps a lot when writing sql.

Comment: my biggest problem is that the first table represents order made from the US (to the be shipped in Brasil), while the second table represents the articles sold by the company in Brasil, which means that this table can have the sell of an article which is not codified in the first table (for example an article not yet order from the US, but probabily will in the future), but that's why I have the third table which joins the US and the Brasilian article in a 1-to-1 relationship...Am I clear enough?

Comment: I cannot create a single table, because I'm not able to link the single quantity sold for the brasilian article to the corresponding US article. I.e. US ships article_A (article_1 for Brasil) in January (1st table). It arrives in February in Brasil, so I have article_1 sold from February (2nd table), but it is sold also in the next months, till it runs out. Then it's order back from US let's say in May. Did you understood my situation? I don't know how to link these tables, apart from the third table which codifies the articles 1:1

Comment: So I have two rows in table 1 (order in Jan and order in May), but I have 3 or more rows in table 2 (Brasil selling the product in Feb, Mar, Apr, may even more than once a month).

Comment: Create the following tables 
tblProducts(fldProductID,fldproductName,+ other fields to store data specifically relating to the PRODUCT).
tblOrder(fldOrderID,fldDate)
tblProductsOrdered(fldProductsOrderedID,fldOrderID,fldProductID,fldPrice)

Comment: Basically you need a table for the product, one for the order, one for the items on the order and you may also need one for the manufacture

Comment: data product related are bill, the exchange rate of the bill, the tax to be paid and other costs that vary each time, they cannot be stored 1:1 with a product...same in brasil, data are revenues, profit, exchange rate...I already have those 3 tables you mentioned...I'm desparetely trying to link them!!!

Comment: there is no 1-to-1 relationship in my example. I have been building database for 10 years and never used 1-to-1 relationship.

Comment: You said: "US ships article_A (article_1 for Brasil) in January (1st table). It arrives in February in Brasil, so I have article_1 sold from February (2nd table), but it is sold also in the next months, till it runs out. Then it's order back from US let's say in May. Did you understood my situation?"

Looks like what you need is a query that counts the number of product sold subtract that from the number of products ordered to get the balance. Remember, tables stores basic data, query works out the rest.

Comment: I was thinking about a query but I have no clue how to set it, especially considering that sales in brasils start (usually) a month after, so I must take into account also this factor...

Comment: create a sample database with the following tables:
tblImportation(fldImportationID,fldImportationDate,fldDeliveryDate)
tblImportedProduct(fldImportedProduct, fldProductId,fldQuantity,fldUSPrice,fldExchangeRate)
tblSales(fldSalesID,fldProductId,fldSaleprice,fldQuantity,fldSaleDate)

The create this query to find how much stuff is left in stock in Brasil as you make sales:
SELECT tblImportation.fldProductId,sum(tblImportedProduct.fldQuantity) - sum(tblSales.fldQuantity) As fldStock 
FROM tblImportedProduct LEFT JOIN tblSales 
ON tblImportedProduct.fldProductId=tblSales.fldProductId

Comment: The create this query to find how much stuff is left in stock in Brasil as you make sales:
SELECT tblImportation.fldProductId,sum(tblImportedProduct.fldQuantity) - sum(tblSales.fldQuantity) As fldStock 
FROM tblImportedProduct LEFT JOIN tblSales 
ON tblImportedProduct.fldProductId=tblSales.fldProductId
GROUP BY tblImportedProduct.fldProductId

This is just and example to demostrate how the inventory component of your database will work. Insert the a few dummy importation and make some dummy sales and see what the query gives you

Comment: I'll give it a go and let you know how I'm going, since I need to find out stock data in Brasil which are not in my documents yet.
Anyway I wanna thank you for your help till now, you gave me good points to think about.

Comment: You need to work out almost everything that you'd want out of a database right from the start. It is IMPORTANT to remember that tables are only for storing RAW data. Query works out the calculated information. For example you should not have field in a table for the quantity of items available on a particular date. One tables should store quantity of products imported and another the quantity sold at each transaction. sum of product imported in table1 minus sum in table 2 gives you the balance. Same rule applies in all circumstances DON'T STORE CALCULATED DATA.